# Why does Chrome yield different event.target than Firefox in some situations?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Given this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/46an3q23/ can someone please help me understand why clicking on the scrollbar in Firefox does not trigger an alert() yet in Chrome it does? Demo code is as follows:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>


$('.container').perfectScrollbar();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#wrap', function(event) {
    alert('container hit');
  });
});
```

I am simply trying to code UX which closes a modal when you click outside of the modal. Strangely, in Chrome, clicking the scrollbar yields an event.target of the #modal (thereby closing the modal incorrectly), whereas in Firefox the target is different and modal is not closed. In production code I am doing event.stopPropagation() but there is no difference.

Thank you

Comment: perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js does `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` when you `mousedown` in the scrollbar. I suspect there's a difference in the way the browsers handle this.

Comment: I appreciate the hint, Barmar, thank you. Unfortunately, I'm unable to find anything online and via my inexperienced attempts to debug the code. I'm totally stumped, but thank you anyway.